# Modulo operation will produce no negative numbers

Tags: java, modulo

I have a little method in java to calculate coordinates. But if one of the coodinates are negative, I only get a 0 instead of the negative number.

```
private static void highlightIslandBorders(Location loc) {
        World world = loc.getWorld();

        int sx = loc.getBlockX();
        sx -= sx % islandSize;

        int sz = loc.getBlockZ();
        sz -= sz % islandSize;

        if ((sx < 0) || (sz < 0)) {
            return;
        }

        int ex = sx + islandSize - 1;
        int ez = sz + islandSize - 1;

        int y = loc.getBlockY() - 1;

        Material cornerMat = Material.GLOWSTONE;
        world.getBlockAt(sx, y, sz).setType(cornerMat);
        world.getBlockAt(ex, y, sz).setType(cornerMat);
        world.getBlockAt(sx, y, ez).setType(cornerMat);
        world.getBlockAt(ex, y, ez).setType(cornerMat);
    }
```

Comment: Is it a minecraft mod/plugin ? What do you want to make with that ?

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly do you get the 0?

```
int islandSize = 3;
int sx = -100;

System.out.println("Mod: " + (sx % islandSize));

sx -= sx % islandSize;
System.out.println("sx: " + sx);
```

Results in

> Mod: -1
>   sx: -99

Comment: https://www.pic-upload.de/view-35393359/Test.png.html
It's the console of my server

Comment: What is islandSize in this example? Also, are you printing the value of sz twice or did you write "sz:" twice by mistake?

Comment: islandSize = 31

Comment: `int islandSize = 31;
int sx = 46;
        
System.out.println("Mod: " + (sx % islandSize));
        
sx -= sx % islandSize;
System.out.println("sx: " + sx);`

Mod: 15
sx: 31

Comment: It works for me, so you probably have something in your code which you are not showing to us.